# to use two tables like a one table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have two different type users table. One of them is ordinary user table for registered users. Other one is for unregistered users.
I need to use these two tables with other tables. For example;

**registered_users:** userid, username, password, name, sex, email, ip

**unregistered_users:** userid, name, sex, ip

**some_table:** id, title, content, userid

How can I join some_table with user table?

I have some oppinion but none of them does not feel right.

1. use all table regUser column and unRegUser column with null values
   and join two table etc. This way non suitable because all tables
   have lots of null cell.
2. if all table like some_table add a column userType and each query
   has "if". But this way is long and spends resources.
3. if userid column type will be string (r13, u32 - r:registered,
   u:unregistered) and use "substring" and "if" but this is more
   difficult
4. create a connection table like "id, type, userid" and use this id
   instead of userid. but also need "if"
5. create a connection table like "id, regUser, unRegUser" with null
   values.

Or create a different user table to be combine of two user tables. Of course we have null columns again.

You think which way is the best? Or any one has different opinion.

Comment: two tables for registered / unregistered users? that's wacky just have a users table with an 'active' column

Comment: What do you need unregistered users for? If they don't register, how do they end up in your DB?

Comment: Not to mention the possibility of double userids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When contents are same why do you try to duplicate it by creating two tables instead you can create a single table called users

```
create table users
(
user_id int not null auto_increment primary key
username varchar(500),
password varchar(500),
email  varchar(400),
ip     varchar(800),
reg_status enum(0,1),
);
```

then you can use this user_id and reference it your secondary table.

You can build up your query on reg_status

```
0 - Unregisterd
1 - Registered
```

If you want more normalized table

then you can use two tables

```
create table users
(
user_id int not null auto_increment primary key
email  varchar(400),
ip     varchar(800),
reg_status enum(0,1),
);


create table registered_users
(
login_id int not null auto_increment primary key
username varchar(500),
password varchar(500),
user_id - F.k (Foreign Key)
);
```

Comment: Of course like that. i embarrassed not to think this today. Thanks a lot :)